# why isnt my javascript object working

Tags: javascript, html, object

```js
var soldier = {
    allegiance : "Ford" ,
    armor: True,
    weapon: "sword" 
};

document.getElementById("soldier").innerHTML = " allegiance: " + soldier.allegiance + " <br/> " + " armor: + " soldier.armor + "Weapon(s): "+ soldier.weapon;
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <script src = "objscript.js" </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id = "soldier"> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this is probably the easiest thing but I don't know what it is. I'm trying to make an object that just prints out the items in the object.

Comment: with out going in details, your code missing > should be <script src = "objscript.js"></script>

Comment: omg im an idiot thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is missing a closing `>` tag.

Plus, it most probably gets executed before the `#soldier` is visible. Thus it throws an error. [Here you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/2119863) find how to execute code after document is ready for it

Also, your `+` next to armor should be outside the quotes.

Also `true` should be all lowercase.

Here's a fix:

```js
var soldier = {
  allegiance: "Ford",
  armor: true,
  weapon: "sword"
};

document.getElementById("soldier").innerHTML = " allegiance: " + soldier.allegiance + " <br/> " + " armor: " +
soldier.armor + "Weapon(s): " + soldier.weapon;
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>

  <html>

  <head>
  
    <script src = "objscript.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="soldier"> </p>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: So, what you're saying is, this question was caused by a typo and therefore will not be useful to future visitors?